# Turkish Characters aren't shown in db when i use dynamic SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, turkish

I've a problem that is about Turksih Characters

I'm using dynamic sql query,when i saw the table Turkish Character is shown in English Charter etc. 's' is seen instead of'ş'. 
When I didn't use Dynamic Query, I haven't any problem.

But I have to use Dynamic Query. My query is:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @Sql = concat('insert into ewrim.', QUOTENAME(@Tc),
     '(', QUOTENAME(@sutunadi1),',',QUOTENAME(@sutunadi2) ,', gun, ay, yil, saat, dakika, islem) ' 
      ,'VALUES (' , @ilk_agirlik,',' , @son_agirlik ,',',convert(varchar(2),day(GETDATE())) ,',',convert(varchar(2),month(GETDATE())) ,',' , convert(varchar(4),year(GETDATE()))  ,',' , convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,GETDATE())) ,',' , convert(varchar(2),datepart(mi,GETDATE())) ,',' ,   char(39), @islem,char(39) ,')')
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should display sql query:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @Sql = concat('insert into ewrim.',...
SELECT @sql;
```

Possible scenarios:

1) Your variable is set as `VARCHAR()`:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(10) = 'ş';
SELECT @s;
-- s
```

should be:

```
DECLARE @s2 NVARCHAR(10) = N'ş';
SELECT @s2;
-- ş
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/KPT25349)**

2) Your column in table does not allow to store specific characters:

```
DECLARE @s2 NVARCHAR(10) = N'ş';

DECLARE @t TABLE (col VARCHAR(10)); -- it depends on locale
INSERT INTO @t(col) VALUES (@s2);

SELECT * FROM @t;
-- s
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/IDTR78018)**